# GAS create alert in server-side validation PropertiesService.getScriptProperties() Spreadsheet ID

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script, google-sheets, alert

I have a spreadsheet which launches a modal dialog form to get information. Some client side validation for required fields but also server side validation: does the input data already exist. Logger.log has not worked for 4 days now so I am using alert. In the server side validation someone wrote you cannot use getActive as you are not in the spreadsheet but in the dialog form. So:

```
function onLoad() {
  
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const ssId = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('ssId', ssId);
```

and in the server side validation - this does not allow me to get to UI in order to send an alert

```
function addMbrCode(myAddForm)  {
  const ssId = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('ssId');
  var ssQ = SpreadsheetApp.openById("[ssId]");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ssQ);
  
  ss.alert("Beginning addMbrCode" );
```

The spreadsheet UI can't be accessed in this context. "open" does not mean "show in browser", it means "open for read and write"... – @Serge insas

So is it possible to issue an alert in this situation?

Comment: Try using modeless dialog or a sidebar.  I find that in most case you can get away with using `.getUi()` in those situations.  Although, I have found some inconsistencies with this approach.

Comment: I think you should use fetchUrl to get data to and from your server while your sheet is being viewed in browser. You could use console.log instead of logger.log and then view the log from the script window, go to view -> executions.

Comment: So you want to send an alert from a script that is not bounded to your Spreadsheet? Have you consider passing a parameter from the server to the client script so that the client can trigger this alert (considering it is a bounded script)? What is the structure of your scripts? Thanks !

Comment: @Mateo Randwolf - I have a spreadsheet that launches a modal dialog that collects information. Some validation needs to be done against the spreadsheet and then the spreadsheet needs to be changed (add or delete row).  I got around the alert problem by writing to a google doc in the server side validation code. I opened a new problem because I cannot updt the spreadsheet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65092183/update-spreadsheet-in-serverside-code-run-from-client-html-javascript-not-workin

Comment: By ```server side validation code``` do you mean the Apps Script ```.gs``` file? Is this an independent script or a [bounded script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) (I assume that the code that triggers your modal dialog comes from a bounded script)? This information is relevant as it will help me reproduce your behaviour as accuratelly as possible. Thanks ! :D

Comment: @Mateo Randwolf - I have a spreadsheet that launches a modal dialog that collects information.  The code is all in the script editor for the spreadsheet. Nothing is standalone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial answer - I wrote my 'logging' to a Google doc on MyDrive.

```
/**
 *  this code is run from the javascript in the html dialog
 */
function addMbrCode(myAddForm)  {
//  cannot access UI to issue alerts on Spreadsheet in this context
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  var myLog = DocumentApp.create('addMbrCode ' +  formattedDate );
  var logId = myLog.getId();
  var body = DocumentApp.openById(logId).getBody();
  var paragraph;
  console.log("Beginning addMbrCode" );
  paragraph = body.appendParagraph('Beginning addMbrCode.');
. . .
      paragraph = body.appendParagraph('end addMbrCode returning: ' + retCd );
      myLog.saveAndClose();
      return retCd;
      
    }
```

However running this server side validation from the javascript in the browser appears to not allow meaningful interaction with my spreadsheet despite @Serge insas comment that "it means "open for read and write". This is probably a new question. I will post separately.

Answer (score 0):

From your questions and comments I have interpreted that you want to trigger a Spreadsheet alert when some validation from data coming from a modal dialog is performed.

For this you would just need to send the data from your `dialog.html` file to your `code.gs` file and then do the validation and execute the alert from that file if the conditions are met. Below I have included a simple example that triggers an alert when the user presses a button in the modal dialog. It contains self-explanatory comments.

Dialog.html:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">
  <script>
    var DIALOG_DIMENSIONS = {width: 600, height: 425};
    
   // if button is pressed execute this function
   function startButton(){
   // launch the functio from our other file which will do the validation and throw 
   // the alert
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(success)
          .withFailureHandler(showError).startAlert();
   }

    function success(){
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'WORKED';
    }

    function showError(message) {
      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Error: ' + message;
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <button onclick='startButton()'>START</button>
    <p id='result'></p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Code.js :

```js
/**
* Creates a custom menu in Google Sheets when the spreadsheet opens.
*/
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Picker')
  .addItem('Start', 'showPicker')
  .addToUi();
}

/**
* Displays an HTML-service dialog in Google Sheets that contains client-side
* JavaScript code for the Google Picker API.
*/
function showPicker() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index.html')
  .setWidth(600)
  .setHeight(425)
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Select a file');
}

function startAlert() {
  // You can add your validation conditions here such as 
  // if this and this then throw this alert
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("ALERT LAUNCHED");
}
```

#### References

- [Modal dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs)
- [alert()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#alertprompt)

Comment: Thanks for your snippet:       google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(success)
          .withFailureHandler(showError).startAlert();  It took me days to figure out the format was not ...Handler(success(result)).  This is included in many examples I found and gives the error 'result' is not defined.  The problem is the code running on the server, launched from the client, does not have access to the SpreadsheetApp.getUi(). This is why I am writing to a Google Doc.  Thank  you for your interest in my problem.

Comment: What do you mean by ```the code running on the server launched from the client```? Where is this code? In which file? Is it something you have on Apps Script? If you could share a sample Spreadsheet with the script files it would be very helpful to fully understand you environment. Thanks ! :D

Comment: this problem was solved by logging to a file. The  other problem documented here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65092183/update-spreadsheet-in-serverside-code-run-from-client-html-javascript-not-workin was a really stupid quotation marks error.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the information provided. :D